# Canvas not loading on IE

Tags: html, canvas

I am working in HTML canvas and it works perfectly on any browser except IE. Does anyone have idea if it is fully supported even though it states that it should be. Or did I make some kind of mistake.

```
 <canvas height="500px" width="500px">
    Doesnt support it
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>
```

You can visit my uploaded version on http://wolfx.one/stars/
or codepen right here: https://codepen.io/lukagurovic/pen/bOxZOq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using arrow functions.  These are not supported in IE, and appear to be a cause of your issues: 
https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Canvas is apparently supported in IE:
https://caniuse.com/#search=canvas

I created a fork of your codepen. However, codepen doesnt seem to work in IE.  But you should see the code in place using a different browser

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPXLrW

e.g.

```
addEventListener('resize', () => { 
    ///...
})
```

should be changed to

```
addEventListener('resize', function() { 
    ///...
})
```

To support IE.

Comment: It actually makes sense, thank you for your answer and if know the way I could replace them please write :) Have a nice day